# Filtering <List> by custom parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am using `react-admin` (v3.2) and am trying to create a custom filter component. 
My entities have an attribute `dateEnd` and I'd like to filter data based on if `dateEnd` is `expired` or `not expired`. I managed to get list of all entities: `expired` and `not expired`.

However I don't know how can I display this list to a user.
Is it possible by somehow creating the query in `URL`?

This is my method that returns the list of `expired` and `not expired` entities:

```js
handleChecked = () => {
  if(this._mounted) 
  {
     this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked, currentDate: new Date()}, () =>
       {
          const currentDateFormated = this.state.currentDate.toISOString();
          if (this.state.msgDates !== null)
          {
             if (this.state.checked === false)
             {
                const notExpired = this.state.msgDates.filter(msg => get(msg, ["publish", "dateEnd"], []) > currentDateFormated);
                        console.log(notExpired, 'NOTEXPIRED');
             }
             else
             {
                 const expired = this.state.msgDates.filter(msg => get(msg, ["publish", "dateEnd"], []) < currentDateFormated);
                        console.log(expired, 'EXPIRED');
              }
           }
      });
   }
}
```

And then I initialize my component in `Filter`:

```js
const MessageFilter = (props) => (
   <Filter {...props}>
     <TextInput source="_id" alwaysOn />
     <TextInput source="layout.caption" alwaysOn />
     <ExpiredFilter alwaysOn />
   </Filter>
);
```

Any ideas how can I show the list of expired or not expired entities?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you intend to filter should be inclusive in that `<List>`.
In your case, your `Resource`/`endpoint` should be returning a `dateEnd` (expired or not). And two design patterns can work here:

> **First,** you could use `filterDefaultValues` prop.
>   **tl;dr** Use a default query (`status`), switch `expired`/`not_expired` (can use `Tabs` to render).

This answers your two questions:

- "Is it possible by somehow creating the query in URL?"
- Any ideas how can I show the list of expired or not expired entities?

```js
<List
  {...props}
  // Do you want your users to start by seeing "expired" or "not expired"?
  // You can place it within `filterDefaultValues`
  filterDefaultValues={{ status: 'not_expired' }}
  sort={{ field: 'date_added', order: 'DESC' }}
  perPage={10}
>{ Children }</List>
```

Then get the `children` component to update that `status` field by using `Tabs`, for example. Those `Tabs` would update your `state` which can be propagated upto the `List`'s `status` prop using `class methods` or `Hooks`.

> **Second,** you can use `filters` prop.
>   *Interestingly, this is what you had in mind but it defeats what you wanted.*
> **tl;dr** Return both `expired` & `not expired` initially, and leave it to the user to query via `filters`.

With this approach, you'd typically render a `List` of both `expired` and `not expired`.
Then provide a `filters` prop to allow a user sieve what they want to see.

```js
<List
  {...props}
  // So you'd place your `MessageFilter` within `filters`
  filters={<MessageFilter />}
  sort={{ field: 'date_added', order: 'DESC' }}
  perPage={10}
>{ Children }</List>
```

Even here, you'd still be querying for that data but no defaults.
So a user will initially see a long list of all your records.

Based on your data, first approach would worked best.
But both `props` can actually be used at the same time depending on your purpose.